# grub:secure boot forbids loading module

Tags: debian, kali-linux

when I tried to set my Kali Linux system to equip it with secure boot. everything is ok(well.....actually not,it used about 10 hours to reach the state).

The shim has pass the check of secure boot but the problem is in grub,it raised me that:

```
secure boot forbids loading module from .....
```

i'm not sure what kinds of addition operates i need to take. may be i need to config the grub. but i have no idea about it.

Answer (score 1):

When using Secure Boot, you will have to use a version of UEFI GRUB that has all the necessary GRUB modules packaged into the main `grubx64.efi` binary, and the binary needs to be signed.

On Debian/Ubuntu, this means installing the `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package: unfortunately, it looks like Kali used to have this package, but it has been removed.

https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/grub-efi-amd64-signed says:

> package is gone
>
> This package is not part of any Kali Linux distribution. Thus you won't find much information here. The package is either very new and hasn't appeared on mirrors yet, or it's an old package that eventually got removed. The old news are kept for historic purpose only.

It appears that Kali Linux currently does not support Secure Boot.

Comment: thanks for your help! but there is a problem. as your description. there have no signed grub-efi package. but it still have unsigned version on apt. and i tried to install it and sign it. but when i boot the computer it raised same issue. how can i do?

Comment: It would be easier to just disable Secure Boot. But you could use `grub-mkimage` to create a version of `grubx64.efi` that includes *all* the modules needed for your configuration, and then sign that. That's essentially what the `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package would contain too.

Comment: i tried your suggestion. and i find a script to config it.thank you very much.thought there still have some problem on it. when i enabled the secure boot,now i can enter the grub successfully.but when i tried to boot the system.it will raised: "verification needed but no body cared:(the name of kernel)". i'm sure that i have sign the kernel with both gpg and sbsigntools. how can i solve it?

Comment: sorry.thought→though and the error is:verification requested but nobody cares

Comment: The error message seems to indicate you now have `hashsum --check` or `verify_detached` command in your GRUB configuration, or the `check_signatures` variable is now set to `enforce`. I suggest you should do more research on what the script you found actually does: it seems to have done more than just creating a Secure Boot compatible signed `grubx64.efi`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks telecoM very much. unfortunatly.i still can't config it successful. I tryed to build a image of grub.i solve the problem of".....but nobody care".but i still can't enter system successfully. it warned me:problem loading x.509 certification (-74). i search on web and found it may be the problem in kernel code. so i can't fix it. maybe this is the end of this question.